# Can you access the calendar and camera on a users phone using an app built with PhoneGap?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, windows-phone

I am planning how to build a web app using PhoneGap for a client, which will present an original web application that's already been built (using Symfony2 and Bootstrap). The client has requested that the app should create events/notifications to the users phone via the calendar, and allow the user to take a photo of something using the app which is then uploaded to the web application.

However, I'm not sure that this is possible using mobile web app's built with something like PhoneGap. There isn't a budget available to build native apps, so PhoneGap (or equivelent) is the only option available to me at the moment.

The client has requested that it works on iPhone/iPad, Android and Windows Phones. I would assume (but I'm not sure at the moment) they would also want it to work on BlackBerry 7/10 devices also. So, is it possible to build an app using PhoneGap that can intergrate with the users calendar and camera?

Comment: fwiw, pg build plugins ... https://build.phonegap.com/plugins . several calendar plugins exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, yes. AFAIK, phonegap is a wrapper so the web app UI that you build (using js, css and html) has access to native phone function such as GPS, camera, even notification. 
as to mentioned in [here](http://phonegap.com/2012/05/02/phonegap-explained-visually/),

> PhoneGap provides an application programming interface (API) that
>   enables you to access native operating system functionality using
>   JavaScript. You build your application logic using JavaScript, and the
>   PhoneGap API handles communication with the native operating system.

You can dip your toe and begin to get used to their APi collection from their website:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/index.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It appears, thus far, that PhoneGap is missing Calendar functionality with IOS, but has it for BlackBerry 10 and Android. But it also looks like this can be circumvented by writing your own PhoneGap plugin to give you this functionality with IOS.